# How to access site not using port

Tags: docker, nginx

Trying to deploy react app with Docker and nginx, can access site only via https://site.app:80. How can I do it without using port number like https://site.app? Please help

dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.2 as build

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
RUN npm run-script build


FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/ssl /etc/ssl
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    server_name site.app www.site.app;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/site.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/site.app.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {
        index   index.html;
    }
}
```

run container

```
docker run -p 80:80 -d registry.gitlab.com/user/site:latest
```

Comment: `https` uses port `443`. Port `80` is for `http`. You might be able to access `http://site.app`  but not `https://site.app`. In that case you have a problem with your ssl configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for http is 80 and for hhtps it's 443 and it's why you don't need to specify them when the webserver listen on theses ports.

In your Dockerfile, you should expose the 2 ports and you should run your container with the two ports:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d registry.gitlab.com/user/site:latest
```

After that, you could navigate to your site using http://site.app and https://site.app.

Comment: added redirect to https and it works! also found that all .app domains are included on the HSTS preload list, making HTTPS required on all connections, that's why http can not work with it

Comment: Right, I forgot about that :)